# The Java File for the txt cannot be found every time it is ran?

Tags: java, exception, text-files, project, hardcode

Everytime I run the code with an exception it lets the user know the file isn't found.
Here is the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try{
        FileReader read = new FileReader("dates in multiple formats.txt");
        BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(read);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}
```

Here is a photo of the file. I am not sure if I am writing the file text wrong.

[image]

Comment: Are you executing the program from inside that directory?

Comment: It seems you have a wrong idea of where your relative path starts. Put `System.out.println(Path.of("").toAbsolutePath());` into your code. It will tell you where your current relative path starts.

Comment: You need to pass in the entire path of the file in FileReader. Java doesn't know where your file exists so it will look in the project by default. You seem to be using Windows so copy the path from there and paste it in your program.

Comment: Also your OS seems to be making the ill-judged decision to hide file extensions. You might want to change that so you can see the file's actual full filename.

Comment: Yes i am getting the information from the text file

Comment: this is apart of my teacher school file thats why it is like such.

Comment: Read about [the working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).